# publish after processing data from 2 synced subscribers (rospy)

Tags: ros, callback, rospy, publisher, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make one node to subscribe 2 topics synchronously, process those data, and publish it.
I know that publishing and subscribing data with single node is possible, but have never seen any example with time synchronization in rospy. This is what I wrote so far (**std_msgs in the code will be replaced with sensor_msgs later on to subscribe RGB image and Point cloud)**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import message_filters
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data1, data2):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id())

def listener():
    sub_1 = message_filters.Subscriber("chatter", String)
    sub_2 = message_filters.Subscriber("sub_chatter", String)
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([sub_1, sub_2], 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
    ts.registerCallback(callback)

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('Publisher', String, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish()
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('SubPub', anonymous=True)
    listener()
    talker()
    rospy.spin()
```

I'm currently getting stuck on how to pass sub_1 and sub_2 to the publisher. I think that I need to **define class** and put everything into that class and use **flag** to publish data whenever callback is called. I'm kind of unsure how to integrate all these features or my idea is even valid. Does anyone have idea or example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375365/publish-after-processing-data-from-2-synced-subscribers-(rospy)/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code has a few bugs.

- In `talker()`, you've got an infinite while() but you don't really do anything there (`pub.publish()` isn't publishing any meaningful content).
- Why do you have both `while not rospy.is_shutdown()` and `rospy.spin()`? Also, `rospy.spin()` is unreachable in your code.

Based on [message_filters Python example](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28Python.29-1), I re-wrote your code (code is untested):

```
def callback(data1, data2):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id())
    ## do stuff with data1 and data2 ##
    pub.publish("some_string")
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('SubPub', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('Publisher', String, queue_size=10)
    sub_1 = message_filters.Subscriber("chatter", String)
    sub_2 = message_filters.Subscriber("sub_chatter", String)
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([sub_1, sub_2], 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
    ts.registerCallback(callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2021-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on 2021-04-04**:
I was just unsure how to pass data1 and data2 to pub.publish(). And yeah, I misunderstood what rospy.spin does. Thank you for pointing it out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-05**:
And just to clarify: nothing will be synced here, or at least not properly. I understand this is only an example/test, but `String` does not have a `std_msgs/Header`, which means, with `allow_headerless=True`, the time at which msgs were received will be used to synchronise them.

This is obviously not what you'd really want in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After processing the data in the call back you can invoke `pub.publish(YOUR_DATA)`, in the callback also.

---

Originally posted by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) with karma: 65 on 2021-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1